# Problemas con la descarga con PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Cordial saludo
Tengo un pequeño gran problema con la descarga de tipo XLSX de un archivo en excel utilizando PHPExcel, he podido descargarlo bien y lo puedo editar normalmente la hoja en la que este parado, pero tengo dos problemas.
1- No me deja copiar los datos que están en el archivo que descargue en otro archivo pero si me deja copiar datos de afuera del archivo en el archivo y me deja copiar datos de la misma hoja dentro de la misma hoja, me aparece que "no se puede ejecutar este comando en selecciones múltiples".
2- No me de crear hojas adicionales al archivo descargado me aparece que "no se puede ejecutar este comando en selecciones múltiples".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`

```
introducir el código aquí
$nomarchivo = "Cargue_temporadas.xlsx";
            $file = $rootdir."files/descargables/".$nomarchivo; 
            //Contenido de ejemplo
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)//Hoja activa
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Consecutivo_temporada') //Datos 
                ->setCellValue('B1', 'Temporada')
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'SAP')
                ->setCellValue('D1', 'Vigencia_desde')
                ->setCellValue('E1', 'Estado')
                ->setCellValue('F1', 'Reglas');

            $fecha = date('d/m/Y',time());
            $fecha = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($fecha);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A2', '05')
                ->setCellValue('B2', 'Nombre Temporada')
                ->setCellValue('C2', '12000011')
                ->setCellValue('D2', "$fecha")
                ->setCellValue('E2', 'Activo')
                ->setCellValue('F2', '1');
            // Get the current date/time and convert to an Excel date/time
    

            // Set the number format mask so that the excel timestamp will be displayed
            //     as a human-readable date/time
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D2')
                ->getNumberFormat()
                ->setFormatCode(
                    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY2
                );


            //Nombre de la hoja
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Plantilla'); 
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);//Hojas activas


            // header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download; charset='utf-8'");
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset='utf-8'");
            header("Content-Type: application/download; charset='utf-8'");;
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$nomarchivo"); //Nombre del archivo
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
            // $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
            $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel); 
            // $objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);

            //Forzar descarga
            $objWriter->save('php://output');`
```

Necesito descargar sin ese problema, ¿podrian ayudarme a solucionarlo?

Comment: Intenta cambiar la linea `$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);` por `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');`. Saludos.

Comment: No funciono, sigue con el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

La forma de corregir ese error fue reemplazar

```
    introducir el código aquí
           // header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-Type: application/force-download; charset='utf-8'");
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset='utf-8'");
            header("Content-Type: application/download; charset='utf-8'");;
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$nomarchivo"); //Nombre del archivo
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
            // $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
            $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel); 
            // $objWriter->setOffice2003Compatibility(true);

            //Forzar descarga
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

`
por

```
    introducir el código aquí
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$nomarchivo);
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            
            //Forzar descarga
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: A veces más simple es mejor...